# What function does `with open(...)` serve while parsing a csv file with `pandas`?

Tags: python, pandas

I just found a notebook [from a book](https://github.com/elegant-scipy/elegant-scipy/blob/master/markdown/ch1.markdown#reading-in-the-data-with-pandas) that has the following construction:

```
filename = 'data/counts.txt'
with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
    data_table = pd.read_csv(f, index_col=0) # Parse file with pandas
```

In what way is that different from simply `data_table = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0)`?

Comment: Umm, how is `f` assigned if you don't have the `with open(filename, 'rt') as f:`, or some *other* actual `open()` invocation? Or does `pd.read_csv()` also accept a string, so you mean to compare against `pd.read_csv(filename, ...)` instead?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `read_csv` does accept a filename. Looking into the link, it seems to have an example of the context manager being used to open a bz2 compressed file... however `read_csv` can read that directly as well: `pd.read_csv('file.bz2', compression='bz2')`. @OP, there's absolutely no need for a context manager unless you're opening the file in append mode to update a CSV.

Comment: It isn't. Both do the same.

Comment: @Valentino, eh? If you take the OP's code, delete the second line, and dedent the third line with no other changes, it'll throw an exception because `f` hasn't been opened or assigned, but the `pd.read_csv()` call refers to it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I mean, both do the same if in the second case `f` is a string with the file name. My point was that pandas can do both ways, and (as far as I know) both ways are equivalent in terms of performance and given results. Sorry if I did not elaborate more before

Comment: I agree with you; I just take issue with pretending the OP said something than what they really did. (Much better to encourage them to change the `f` to `filename` in the final paragraph of the question, should that be their intent).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree on that. As a matter of fact, the final paragraph is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) can accept a couple of different types in the first argument.  The documentation says `filepath_or_buffer : str, path object, or file-like object`.

When you run `pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0)` you are asking pandas to find and open the file for reading.

When you run

```
with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
    data_table = pd.read_csv(f, index_col=0)
```

you opening the file beforehand and passing pandas a file object/buffer for it to read.

Both accomplish the same thing.  If you want more control about how the file is opened/read, you would do the latter.

Comment: For example: you want to skip the first `n` lines.  But I believe `read_csv` has an optional argument for that as well!